# iOS 11 issues with Refresh Controller and navigationBar that has prefersLargeTitles set to true

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, swift4

I am using a navigation controller and within that navigation controller, I have a VC with a tableview that is hugging the top, bottom, left and right sides of the superView. When I have `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles` set to false, everything works fine. But when I set it to true, I have to drag really really far down to get my refresh controller to trigger the refresh.

This is fixed by simply tapping one cell which then goes into the detail view and then pressing the back button from the detail view to go back to the vc with the main tableview and refresher. After doing that the pull to refresh works perfectly with the large titles. Very weird!

I have a very basic setup of my tableview. My actual project has a more complex setup but in order to isolate this problem, I created a much simpler project with the same tableview and the issue persisted. Has anybody else seen this issue? I am thinking it is an issue on apple's end but I wanted to check if I was doing something wrong on my end.

I am using swift 4 and iOS 11.0.2 with Xcode 9.

The animator starts to animate but when it gets a certain (the point where it should refresh), it just stops. When I keep on pulling down further and further, it does the refresh. But it should have done it much earlier. I have to pull down to the point where the nav bar stretches to almost the entire length of the screen. See the screenshot. [image]

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: having a hard time this the same issue. were you able to solve it?

Comment: Yes, I call manually called the refresh controller when the scroll view gets to a certain offset. That offset you need to determine based on how your scroll view is set up. I am also having issues when a user scrolls down and the larger title becomes smaller. the animation is not smooth for some reason. i am hoping it is an apple thing that they fix.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to set self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;

Answer (score 0):

You try this by adding the constraint of tableview.top to View.top of ViewController instead of topLayoutGuide

[image]

Comment: I have tried this but it does not solve the problem. If you set it to the top of the view, there are a bunch of problems when you have the large titles enabled.